# Is there a way to update the query connection file name in Excel by macro?

Tags: excel, vba, connection-string

In my summary file I have a handful of query connections that take another Excel file in the same file folder as input file for data connection.
The input file name changes periodically, so every time it changes, I need to go to each query connection to change the name of the data source, which can be cumbersome. 
I am trying to find a way to batch update the connection file name using macro.

I tried to identify and access the parameter for the filename but can't seem to find the right approach.

```
Sub Check_Queries()

    Dim filename As String
    Dim query
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each query In ActiveWorkbook.Connections

        Print query.OLEDBConnection.SourceConnectionFile

    Next query

End Sub
```

It returns this error:

> Compile error: Method not valid without suitable object.

[image]

=======================================================================

After I have been spotted the error of missing the 'Debug.' before 'Print', I continued to work out the solution and discovered that **the parameter for the task is Activeworkbook.Queries.Formula**. I wrote the following sub and tested it to be working as intended. Comments on improving the code are welcome.

```
Sub Update_Queries()

Dim start As Integer
Dim finish As Integer
Dim query
Dim code As String
Dim oldPath As String
Dim newPath As String
Dim intChoice As Integer

Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
intChoice = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
If intChoice <> 0 Then
    newPath = Application.FileDialog( _
    msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)

    For Each query In ActiveWorkbook.Queries

        code = query.Formula
        'Debug.Print code
        start = InStr(code, "File.Contents(")
        finish = InStr(start + 15, code, "), null, true")

        If start <> 0 And finish <> 0 Then

            oldPath = Mid(code, start + 15, finish - start - 16)
            'Debug.Print oldPath
            If Not oldPath = "" Then

                query.Formula = Replace(code, oldPath, newPath)

            Else

                Debug.Print Right(code, InStr(code, "), null, true"))
                query.Formula = Left(code, start + 14) & newPath & Right(code, InStr(code, "), null, true"))

            End If

            code = ""
            start = Empty
            finish = Empty
            oldPath = ""

        End If

    Next query

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you forget the `Debug.` in front of `Print`?

Comment: Yes, that was my bad.